# "the sound was premium external" what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm translating [Vernor Vinge's Rainbows End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbows_End), there's a line I don't understand:

"The Problem Is, None Of You Think Nearly Enough." The sound was premium external, like sticking your head inside an old-time boom box.

What does it mean, "the sound was premium external"? as "external" is an adjective, "premium" can't be adjective here, so should be a noun? then as a noun "premium" is referring to money, not able to describe the sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a strange sentence, even to a native speaker. You could probably interpret either word as being a noun.

Take for example the phrase "time eternal," which bears a resemblance to your phrase.

> [A] time [that is] eternal

It too is often used without an article. In a similar form, your phrase would mean:

> The sound was [a] premium [thing that was] external

Though upon first reading, I read it the other way around with "external" as the noun:

> The sound was [a] premium external [thing].

The grammatical difference is slight, but the semantics probably amount to the same.

Comment: What does premium mean then , to describe a sound?

Comment: @athos It doesn't mean a sound, no. See the last sentence; it's a premium external thing, i.e. a rare special thing that comes externally to affect the senses. You just know it means a sound due to the context.